# Binding of output events from child to parent component

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a unit test for method ngAfterViewInit in my component code for the coverage. I am using Jasmine karma as my test tool. At the moment the code coverage complains that
this.closeModal() which is called part of the subscribe is not covered.

Basically , i am passing the childcomponent reference to the parentcomponent. As you can see the child component has output event called closeModal. The parent component is subscribing to it. I did the following in my test as you can see in the code below. That is binding the closeModal output event to the parent component and try to emit the event via the child component. That doesnt seem to work as well. Is there a problem with the way that i am binding.

```
 component.ngAfterViewInit();
    component.closeModal.bind(childComponent.closeModal);
    component.componentRef.instance.closeModal.subscribe(() => {
      tick();
       childComponent.closeModal.emit(true);
      expect(component.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Parent component

```
export class ModalDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly _onClose = new Subject<any>();

  public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
  public childComponentType: Type<any>;
  public onClose = this._onClose.asObservable();

  // add this:
  @ViewChild(InsertionDirective, { static: false })
  insertionPoint: InsertionDirective;

  constructor(public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              public cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
              public dialog: ModalDialogRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadChildComponent(this.childComponentType);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  loadChildComponent(componentType: Type<any>) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
    const viewContainerRef = this.insertionPoint.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.componentRef.instance.closeModal.subscribe(() => this.closeModal());
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent {
  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  constructor(public config: ModalDialogConfig,
              public dialog: ModalDialogRef
              ) {}

  onCancel() {
    this.dialog.close('user clicked cancel');
  }

  onOk() {
    this.dialog.close('User clicked ok');
  }
}
```

Test

```
fdescribe('ModalDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalDialogComponent;
  let childComponent: ExampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalDialogComponent>;
  let childFixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let mockMouseEvent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, ModalDialogModule, NgxsModule.forRoot([])],
      providers: [ModalDialogConfig, ModalDialogRef ]
    })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [ModalDialogComponent, ExampleComponent] } })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalDialogComponent);
    childFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
    mockMouseEvent = new Mock<MouseEvent>({ stopPropagation: () => Promise.resolve(true) });
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    childComponent = childFixture.componentInstance;

    component.childComponentType = ExampleComponent;

    component.componentRef = childFixture.componentRef;
    spyOn(component.componentRef.instance, 'closeModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call ngAfterViewInit ', () => {

    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    component.closeModal.bind(childComponent.closeModal);
    component.componentRef.instance.closeModal.subscribe(() => {
      tick();
        childComponent.closeModal.emit(true);
      expect(component.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });

  });
```

Comment: Note that `spyOn(component.dialog, 'close').and.callThrough();` will **not** call(execute) the method, but will make sure that the spy, when called, will use the original function instead of a stubbed one.

Comment: Then why is not covering the method that i am looking to cover

Comment: Are you sure that `this.componentRef.instance.closeModal` emits?

Comment: I think it emits as once i got an error regarding it emitting

Comment: basically by subscribe is looking for an event which its not finding

Comment: So I think you should make `this.componentRef.instance.closeModal` emit something, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209868/discussion-between-tom-and-andrei-gtej).

Comment: I have updated the post with more information and my most recent investigations. Could you let me know what you think ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209880/discussion-between-tom-and-andrei-gtej).

Comment: The issue has been fixed. I had to just add this line of code  component.componentRef.instance.closeModal.emit(true);

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. I had to add just this line of code 
  component.componentRef.instance.closeModal.emit(true);